# MvcReportViewer - posting multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have an MVC project and I'm using the MvcReportViewer from https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer. This works fine when using parameters that accept single strings...

Assuming we have an SSRS report which has a dropdown list of a multivalue type, called 'myArrayOfLocations' I want to post something such as

```
@Html.MvcReportViewerFluent(ViewData["ReportUrl"].ToString()).Method(
FormMethod.Post).ReportParameters(
new {ID=3, myArrayOfLocations="UK,France,Germany,Spain,USA"}).Attributes(new { Height = 900, Width = 900, style = "border: none", frameBorder = "0" })
```

The above code 'should' then place ticks in the dropdown box, but doesn't!

If I just set myArrayOfLocations="UK" - it binds fine.

What am I doing wrong?

I should mention that I'm passing the parameters from the controlller into ViewData[] as a "List>" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to loop through all the values and add them one by one as keyvaluepairs.

ex:

```
reportParams.Insert(reportParams.Count, new KeyValuePair<string, object>("myArrayOfLocations", "UK"));

reportParams.Insert(reportParams.Count, new KeyValuePair<string, object>("myArrayOfLocations", "France"));
```

repeat.. for each value.
Hope that helps.